# Macbook Air 2020 M1 consumes SSD life too fast

Tags: ssd, apple-silicon

Macbook Air 2020 M1 consumes SSD life too fast. The SSD wrote twice as much data in two weeks as the Macbook Retina 2017 did in two years. I use VSCodium and Google Chrome for Web development. I haven't downloaded anything other than those programs. I haven't logged into iCloud. I have not connected any iPhones to this laptop. I haven't even downloaded old projects. I don't know exactly, I estimate my data on the SSD to be less than 1-5GB considering the programs I have installed in unpacked state. That said, smartctl shows that I have written 17Tb of data to the SSD and continue to write 1Tb daily. I honestly don't understand how this can be. I keep working on my old macbook with the same programs VSCodium and Google Chrome. The smartctl program says I'm writing about 20-30Mb per day. The number of writes to the SSD only goes up when I download files from the internet.

I have never tried XCode. Maybe there are special programs for Macbook M1 for web development.

If I replace VSCodium with XCode and Google Chrome with Safari, can my mac survive the rest of this year?

**UPDATE**

There is another tool `iostat`.

Let's see what the third column of the iostat output shows.
In the first screenshot I caught a not very good moment for comparison. When I ran the utility, Chrome Browser was loaded. The second screenshot corrects this awkwardness. The third screenshot is the old Macbook Retina 2017 running under a fairly high load. `i7core != m1core`

To get this low write rate on the MacBook Air SSD, I had to turn Spotlight off. I also (not sure if that helps) disabled Time Machine.
Yesterday's SSD write indications were 20-50 times higher.

On the old macbook, I didn't turn anything off. Not the browser, not VSCodium, not Spotlight, not Time Machine. Plus I have two VeraCrypt disk images connected.

[image: apple-m1-iostat]
[image: apple-m1-iostat in idle]
[image: apple-i7-iostat]

[image: apple-m1-fs_usage-1]
[image: apple-m1-fs_usage-2]
[image: apple-m1-fs_usage-3]

Comment: When you say too fast, is this for comfort or do you have some specification that indicates a useful life of Apple T2 based media?

Comment: https://mjtsai.com/blog/2021/02/26/excessive-mac-ssd-wear/

Comment: I believe there is a bug that Apple is trying to address with SSDs degrading faster on the new M1 Macs. It's been reported on a number of news sites. At the moment, I don't know if there is a fix, but keep an eye out for a fix soon!

Comment: I hear you. We should sell this Macbook Air with the M1 and work on the old laptop until they adapt Rosetta Stone not to eat up so many resources. RAM is always busy at a minimum of 2-6Gb (10+Gb free). But the swapfile is 40+Gb busy. And no one talks about it and no one warned about it.

Comment: On every corner screamed that 8GB RAM will be enough laptop, there is no point in overpaying for 16GB. The secret of performance is out. They simply configured the SSD to use it as RAM.

Comment: According to the discussion here (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7734134) and your numbers you can still use the SSD for 9 more years, which should be enough for you?

Comment: @JoyJin According to that discussion, the SSD has a lifetime of 400TBW. Writing 1Tb of data per day, perhaps the SSD will live until the end of the year. The problem is that I don't do anything on this laptop. The laptop eats up 1Tb a day of SSD when it is idle. How will its appetite increase when I start doing things on it?

Comment: @DiD You haven't really established (yet) that your laptop eats up 1 Tb/day. The screenshots you have of iostat are not really useful, as it does not say whether it is reads or writes. It is only writes we're interested in here. Try using a command such "sudo fs_usage -f diskio -t 1" in order to get detailed information.

Comment: These screenshots are hardly readable. Can you please include the relevant part into your question as text (copy/paste from Terminal) and format as code?

Comment: @DiD Could you paste some description of what your various disk* are? I.e. the first screenshots concern /dev/disk0 and the latter concern /dev/disk3. Something like the output from "diskutil apfs list" would help here.

Comment: @jksoegaard All drive partitions are configured by default. I have not changed anything. I don't even know how to do it,  had known that, I would have tried all the options. disk0 is a physical disk with an APFS container. disk3 is the container itself. disk3s1 is the partition with all the data. disk3s3s1 is the weird APFS System Snapshot partition (takes 15 GB, not mounted)

Comment: @nohillside I will of course include all the necessary information in text form. But from the screenshots it is more or less clear that these system utilities in this form do not give any useful information. Most of the disk logs are made by processes named: kernel_task, launchd, identityservices, routined, mds_stores (in descending order). These processes do not share any useful information about their activities.

Comment: @DiD I did not say that you have changed anything - I just wanted to learn the layout. Regarding the fact that the processes "do not share any useful information", they actually do. You can use dtrace to see what kind of activities they perform.

Comment: Have you tried looking at Activity Monitor to see which program is writing the most to the disk? - It would give you an indication of how much is actually written to the disk - and then we can know more.

Comment: The screenshots are hardly readable (and not readable at all for people with screenreaders), also the right hand side seems not to be necessary at all.

Comment: @jksoegaard I don't know how to use dtrace. I tried reinstalling MacOS by erasing the hard drive partition. A fresh copy of the system only made things worse. How can I share an ssh connection without having a dedicated ip address? If anyone is interested, I can at least share the desktop screen. I don't care about the laptop anymore. This is the worst computer I've ever had in my entire experience with Apple hardware. I'm ashamed of the people I advised to buy the same macbook.

Comment: I’m sorry - but are you saying that you have a computer in any way performs exactly as you would like, but you have read an article online that says that your computer “might” (as in totally unverified) have a drive will less life time than normally, and now you consider this the worst computer ever? I think you need to recalibrate your thoughts here - for all we know, this might be a total non-issue and the drives last 15 years or similar.

Comment: Sharing connection without a dedicated IP can be done by using for example openport.io - or you can use TeamViewer or similar for remote desktop access. If you want help with using dtrace and other system software to determine if there is an excessive amount of writes on your system, I would suggest going to the chat and we can help there!

Answer (score 3):

Don't get carried away with news stories. This is the main takeaway.

There's a number of reasons why you shouldn't be worried or concerned (yet).

In the comments you indicate that Apple somehow secretly configured the SSD to use it as RAM. This is not the case - this is not how of any of that works. When a Mac runs out of RAM, it uses the disk as a replacement - this is known as "swapping". It is a basic technique used on all Macs (not only M1s) and is also used on all other modern operating systems such as Windows, Linux, etc.

There's no indication anywhere that the M1 Mac swaps more than an Intel Mac with the same amount of RAM.

There's also no indication anywhere that the SSD in the M1 Mac Mini is somehow "worse" or degrades faster than SSDs in comparable Intel Macs.

The whole scary news story here hinges on the fact that a SMART value is seemingly high on these machines. However, it is really jumping to a conclusion that this means that the drive is actually degrading or that the machine will stop working in a short while. For multiple reasons:

1. These numbers could very well be interpreted incorrectly. SMART values have always been problematic in that different disk vendors use slightly different definitions and units, and sometimes do not report numbers according to standards - and that their reporting might even change on the same hardware just with newer firmware.

It could very well be that the numbers are a factor 1000 off because the units are wrong. We cannot know that. Remember that on the M1 Mac, we do not have a direct connection to a Samsung SSD controller or similar (that we have been used to on older Macs) - but rather everything goes through the special Apple integrated disk controller that handles security.

The right thing here is to contact Apple for clarification on how the numbers should be interpreted.

2. It is not so that a SSD drive just suddenly stops working when the lifetime left indicator raches 0%. That's not how this works. Essentially the drive keeps a score of usage, and the vendor has built in some more or less arbitrary threshold number. It could be that this number represents what the vendors will treat as warranty cases, it could be that this number represents what the vendor think is the an average drive's life time - or it could just be any old random number.

In practice it is very common for drive manufacturers to have this threshold be much lower than the actual average life time of drives.

Without confirmation from Apple we cannot really conclude that this number means anything in practice.

In any case, if the drives in M1 Macs should die from ordinary usage in less than a year, Apple would have to replace those drives for everyone.

So either (a) the numbers that you make lots of conclusions from are not correctly interpreted, or (b) Apple made a huge oversight and sold products that wear out much faster than ordinary.

Without further information, I would assume (a) is the most likely. Press Apple for more information and we can know for sure. If (b) is the case, Apple would have to do a recall program of some sort.

Comment: [I agree with the message here](https://www.macworld.com/article/338844/how-worried-should-you-be-about-your-m1-macs-ssd-lifespan.html). We have not been able to burn through any Mac SSD at work despite 24x7 use of them, [Minis running IO intensive tomcat apps, syncing thousands of GB of data a year, caching servers that churn constantly, Xcode CI/CD drone Macs, log files writing constantly, etc...](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/416328/5472)  AppleCare can immunize anyone from an Apple misstep as large as is proposed here very well if somehow they juggled the trade-offs incorrectly on M1.

Comment: I added some information to the question.
Ok. SMART values can lie (be misinterpreted). Can the kernel lie? Can those megabytes be interpreted as kilobytes?

Comment: The screenshots you have added of iostat are not really useful, as it does not say whether it is reads or writes. It is only writes we're interested in here. Try using a command such "sudo fs_usage -f diskio -t 1" in order to get detailed information.

Comment: And no, those megabytes in iostat cannot be interpreted as kilobytes. However, it is really not that useful information, because those megabytes could be megabytes _read_ and not _written_. Have you taken a look at Activity Monitor to see which program(s) are writing a lot to the disk?

Answer (score -2):

Reinstalling MacOS doesn't solve the problem. But I did find a solution for myself. The solution is probably not suitable for active Spotlight users. This recipe probably won't help everyone. But it helped me a lot.

First, I removed all the checkboxes in the system settings Spotlight. I also added the file system root to the indexing exceptions. This was not necessary to do. But it solved the problem by 50%.

Next, open a terminal and type a command:

```
  sudo mdutil -i off -a
```

Enter the password. After running the command, the terminal will list Stoplight search folders and after each folder should be the phrase:

```
 Indexing and searching disabled.
```

Then turn off the computer. After that, we turn on the computer in RecoveryOS mode. For M1 Macbooks it is activated by a long press on the Power button (keep the button pressed for about 10 seconds).

On the black screen choose from two options *cogwheels*.

Then in the main menu select `Utilites` -> `Terminal`.

Type the command: `csrutil disable`. Then enter the password.
Then we need to restart computer in normal mode. This can be done quickly by typing `reboot` in the same terminal.

When the system is booted, open the terminal again and type the command:

```
  sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

Enter the password again. These actions were enough to solve my problem.

[image: MacBook-m1-iostat]

After that, you can reboot the computer again in RecoveryOS, turn on the terminal and type the command `csrutil enable`. But if you are the only user of the computer and you understand what you are doing, it is not necessary to enable CSR protection.

If you need a working Spotlight, as I mentioned at the beginning, this is probably not the solution for you. It's everyone's choice - some people value the integrity of an SSD. But, there will be people who are ready to tolerate 1TB of daily SSD wear and tear for the sake of a working Spotlight.

As an alternative, [Quicksilver](https://qsapp.com) might be a good replacement for Spotlight. This program is free and open source.

Comment: This answer does not seem right at all. Spotlight does a lot of READs, which you see in iostat - this is particularly true just after installing the OS. This is perfectly normal, have always been the case also on Intel Macs, and it DOES NOT wear your SSD. Your SSD wears from WRITES to the drive. As you disable SIP, I would consider this answer really bad advice.

Comment: @jksoegaard Spotlight does not index anything. In my case, it endlessly restarts thousands of times per second leaving in the logs (com.apple.mdworker.shared.05000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[xxxx]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[48]

Comment: So did it do this from the default install? - or only after you started doing your own changes to the system?

Comment: @jksoegaard I purposely deleted the APFS partition disk3 to reset it. What I did after installation: selected the system language, selected the time zone, selected the keyboard layouts, skipped accessibility settings, connected to the wifi network, skipped connecting to with AppleID, skipped data migration, unchecked the checkbox to use Siri

Comment: So you did not do any of the csrutil disable stuff, right? - Looks like you have something that accesses/updates a file very rapidly. Use "fs_usage filesys" to discover what it is.

Comment: @jksoegaard I disabled CSR after confirming the diagnosis that nothing has changed. sudo iostat works with CSR enabled. What kind of information does Spotlight index in an empty user folder?

Comment: @jksoegaard This time I installed the system via DFU. This is the system image: http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2021WinterFCS/fullrestores/071-14756/5676903C-6D55-4412-B9DF-969F15F5491A/UniversalMac_11.2.3_20D91_Restore.ipsw

Comment: Don’t disable CSR. In order for me to be able to help you diagnose the problem with your laptop, you need to run the indicated command. It will tell you which file or files are being accessed.

Comment: @jksoegaard  I ran `sudo fs_usage -f diskio -t 300`. This resulted in a poorly informative output as in these screenshots [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrFFv.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FscL4.jpg) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Na0t.png) (in left half). I have never used dtrace before, much less the Sun version. I'm more used to strace when the source code is available.

Comment: fs_usage is not dtrace. I don't know why, but if you think strace is better because the source code is available - I can tell you that dtrace is also open source. You can grab the source here: https://github.com/opensource-apple/dtrace

Comment: Regarding the poorly informative output - I don't know why you think it is poor - it looks OK to me. Your screenshots however do not include anything about Spotlight. You said that the problem was that Spotlight keeps hammering your disk - but you seem to have traced in periods where Spotlight was not doing anything. Could you try again when the problem is present?

Comment: @jksoegaard Sorry my English. You misunderstood me. I know that dtrace is open source. What I meant to say is that it is easier for me to debug linux because it compiles and linking on my computer. And I have mapping with binary code and source code. I can set breakpoints and execute code by step-by-step.  And debugging a kernel without source code is reverse-engineering.

Comment: I have no idea why in the world you want the kernel source code to do this here. That does not make sense. However, you're in luck! The kernel source for macOS is open source - so you can download the Darwin source code. You can also setup the kernel debugger to setup breakpoints and execute code step-by-step. No reverse-engineering needed anywhere.

Comment: Anyways, when debugging problems like this on Linux - I don't use the kernel source code, and I don't use a kernel debugger. I use ordinary tools like dtrace for Linux (or systemtap). This is not about hardware malfunctioning, this is not about kernel bugs - this is about ordinary user space programs behaving badly.

Comment: @jksoegaard It seems to me that the major workload is not the Spotlight itself, but the system that constantly reloads it. So, when I disabled it completely, the system started to work without the pressure on the SSD. The new M1 processors and SSD are very fast, and the multi-core structure of the system as a whole allows to work during bugs and not noticed them. This is what is most scary. If such a bug showed up on Intel, it would be impossible to work at this computer. And the user would be forced to react. In  M1 this bug allows the computer to self-destruct unnoticed by the user.

Comment: That is sadly not really true. There' no such special "multi-core" structure of the M1 that is different from Intel CPUs. You seem to be intent on blaming this on the M1, no matter what the cause is. You won't get your problem solved this way.

Comment: @jksoegaard I didn't mean any kind of kernel magic. It's just that when I see loadavg in the 1.8-2.5 range on a Macbook with i7, it's so slow and hot you could fry eggs on it. When I run the OpenGL test on the m1, the average can fluctuate between 16-24. ARM cores are simple, consume little power, give off little heat, you can put more such cores in a laptop. Intel x86_64 with heavy overloaded legacy functionality for at least next 3-5 years can not put in a laptop with passive cooling of its 8 cores, such a laptop will burn a kilowatt.

Comment: High load averages does not in itself mean that the CPU is busy. You can have a load average of 100 on an Intel CPU without using much CPU time at all. By the way Intel produces CPUs with 6W TDPs for example. In any case, this has nothing to do with the original question. Your problem is not in any way at all caused by the CPU being an M1.